# Given the artifact, is it possible to know what maven repo hosts it?

Tags: maven

Say i am looking to include some [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) libraries to my project. I am [told](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/13.0.1) that this is a proper way to ask Maven to get it for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, this is all great, assuming Maven repo i am pointing to actually has this code.

**Is it possible to know what repo of many out there has particular binary for you to download? Put differently, assuming the repo you point to does not have what you need, where should you point to get it?**

Let me elaborate. My pom currently lists the following repo:

```
<repository>
    <id>JBOSS_NEXUS</id>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</repository>
```

Unless my eyes are fooling me, guava libraries are not present on that [server](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/com/google/guava/guava/) (in this version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven has no way to know what Maven repositories are out there in the world. It can only see the repositories you declare.

Unless you've worked extra hard, you always have the Maven Central repository, and then any others. Pretty nearly everything you want is on central: use [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/) to search it.

If something you want isn't on central, there's not much you can do to find out if it is somewhere else.

Comment: Is this the one `repo1.maven.org`?

Comment: That's the URL of central, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Generally with Maven dependencies unless you are explicitly told otherwise, you would expect to find them in maven central, which is the default place maven looks and doesn't need to be configured explicitly.